How to search for text in a Looker Studio report?
I created a Report using Looker Studio. The Data Source is a Google Sheet. The Report got created with hundreds of rows. The Report has a Pivot table which spans a single Page. To look at all the rows, I need to scroll through the Page. There is no way to do a Ctrl F to find a certain text on the page. Please let me know if I am missing something.
